# How to add project to Android Build?

Tags: android, recursion, build, makefile, gnu

I'm having a problem with building an Android ROM (galaxys2att, gingerbread). I decided it was time to get smarter about makefile processing. So I created a simple test project to play with. But it's **not** getting compiled. Here's what I did:

1 I create a directory ("*myproject/*") under a buildable module (I used "*Mms/*" but others had the same problem).
2 I create `Android.mk` in that directory containing

> hello:
>
> ```
>    echo "Hello from myproject"
> ```

(I have no blank line between hello: and echo: the page editor added these)

3 I ran `mm` in the "*Mms/*" directory.

Mms and other subproject compiled but no evidence of myproject.

Android.mk in Mms contained line
`include $(call all-makefiles-under, $(LOCAL_PATH))`

Of course I ran `envsetup.sh` originally.
What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Android NDK, there's some documentation in `.../docs/ANDROID-MK.html`. Unfortunately, there's not much other documentation to find, beside looking into existing makefiles. A minimal `Android.mk` for building a shared library, might look like this

```
# "initialize" Makefile
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

# setup some variables
LOCAL_MODULE    := hello-jni
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := hello-jni.c

# do the build
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

An `Android.mk` is not like a regular Makefile. You have a boilerplate, define some variables needed in sub makefiles and then do the work by including predefined Android makefiles.

`BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY`, for example, is defined in `build/core/build-all.mk` as

```
BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY := $(BUILD_SYSTEM)/build-shared-library.mk
```

which itself defines and checks some make variables and then includes `$(BUILD_SYSTEM)/build-module.mk`, and so on.

Inside build-all.mk, there are other variables defined as well, like `BUILD_HOST_EXECUTABLE`, `BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY` or `BUILD_EXECUTABLE`, which are used to build a static library or an executable.

Comment: Thank you very much for responding. I will try this out.  -John